# lucidworks enterprise crawling does not index my data

Tags: lucene, solrnet

I configured lucidworks enterprise to use data in my sql server database . 
when i start lucid to crawl my data, unfortunately no index create!

thanks

Comment: Maybe you should contact the support?

Comment: Post what you have tried.  Maybe a code sample or something?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/home/LucidWorks+Documentation+Center). The details on loading data are given [here](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/bigdata/Loading+Data)